# Set two different "geometry" style into the same document .tex

Tags: margins, geometry

Without to create two different `*.tex` files, can I have the first page (the cover page) with another style geometry than the rest of the document? So that it does not leave me so much empty space on the left and fills the entire page? I want to leave the next pages unchanged.

I've read something about the [`combine`](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf) package
but I don't know how I should proceed for my document considering that I have used `geometry` package.

I glue an image of my MWE with a screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=7cm,rmargin=.7cm,bmargin=2cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=2em]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes,tabularx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr, scaled=1.1]{rsfso}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,lipsum}

\parindent 0cm

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
 \begin{LARGE}
 \textsc{UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI BORA BORA}\\
 \end{LARGE}
\begin{center}
\textsc{DIPARTIMENTO DI SCIENZE GEOLOGICHE}\\
\textsc{DIPARTIMENTO DI FISICA ED ASTRONOMIA}\\
\rule{12cm}{2pt}%
\vspace{-.4cm}
\rule{10cm}{.1pt}%
\end{center}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}
\textit{Geofisica}
\end{center}
\end{large}
\begin{Huge}
 \textbf{BLA BLA\\BLA\\BLA}\\
\end{Huge}
\vspace{5.5cm}
\begin{large}
\emph{Name + Surname}\\
\end{large}
\vspace{3cm}
\begin{large}
\emph{Prof. Albert Einstein}\\
\end{large}
\rule{10cm}{.1pt}%
\vspace{-.68cm}
\rule{12cm}{2pt}%
\begin{LARGE}
\textsc{ANNO ACCADEMICO 2017--2018}\\
\end{LARGE}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\end{center}


\section{Sviluppo in multipoli di potenziali del tipo newtoniani}

\subsection{Premessa}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\newgeometry` for the title page and after it `\restoregeometry`.
It takes the same arguments as geometry. Just one example of a new geometry:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[lmargin=7cm,rmargin=.7cm,bmargin=2cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=2em]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes,tabularx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr, scaled=1.1]{rsfso}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,lipsum}

\parindent 0cm

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{lmargin=.7cm, %% <-- added
             rmargin=.7cm,
             bmargin=2cm,
             marginparwidth=5.5cm,
             marginparsep=2em}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\textsc{UNIVERSITÀ DEGLI STUDI DI BORA BORA}\\
\end{LARGE}
\begin{center}
\textsc{DIPARTIMENTO DI SCIENZE GEOLOGICHE}\\
\textsc{DIPARTIMENTO DI FISICA ED ASTRONOMIA}\\
\rule{12cm}{2pt}%
\vspace{-.4cm}
\rule{10cm}{.1pt}%
\end{center}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{large}
\begin{center}
\textit{Geofisica}
\end{center}
\end{large}
\begin{Huge}
\textbf{BLA BLA\\BLA\\BLA}\\
\end{Huge}
\vspace{5.5cm}
\begin{large}
\emph{Name + Surname}\\
\end{large}
\vspace{3cm}
\begin{large}
\emph{Prof. Albert Einstein}\\
\end{large}
\rule{10cm}{.1pt}%
\vspace{-.68cm}
\rule{12cm}{2pt}\\%
\begin{LARGE}
\textsc{ANNO ACCADEMICO 2017--2018}\\
\end{LARGE}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\end{center}

\restoregeometry %% <-- added
\section{Sviluppo in multipoli di potenziali del tipo newtoniani}

\subsection{Premessa}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: result]